# How to make two variables generate unique values from the same list in Python?

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to code a card game. But I am stuck at the part of dealing 2 unique cards to "player 1" and "player 2" from the same `cards` list.

How can I get the "player 2" to receive cards that have *not* been dealt to "player 1"?

```
cards=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

player_1 = random.sample(cards, 2)
player_2 = random.sample(cards, 2)

print(player_1)
print(player_2)
```

Example results:

```
["f", "e"]
["f", "c"]
```

The problem above is that I end up with both players getting an 'f' even though there is only 1 'f' in the list.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easier solutions would be to do it kind of like real life, shuffle the deck and then deal your cards.
Python has a [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) method

So you could do

```
# Initial set of cards
cards = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
# Shuffle is in place, so the original cards variable gets shuffled
random.shuffle(cards)
# Take the first half, using slice notation 
cards_player1 = cards[0:2]
# Take the second half of the cards
cards_player2 = cards[2:]
```

(Quick note, I am using slice notation: a[start:stop] yielding items start through stop-1. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works) explains this notation in more detail.)

This would also be expandable to having more players, since the shuffle always just 'shuffles the cards', and you just have to split the stack of cards between your players so that each has the desired amount.

Answer (score 1):

You could deal for a deck with the `.pop()` method of a list:

```py
>>> deck = [n+s for n in 'A23456789TJQK' for s in '♠♣♥♦']
>>> deck
['A♠', 'A♣', 'A♥', 'A♦', '2♠', '2♣', '2♥', '2♦', '3♠', '3♣', '3♥', '3♦', '4♠', '4♣', '4♥', '4♦', '5♠', '5♣', '5♥', '5♦', '6♠', '6♣', '6♥', '6♦', '7♠', '7♣', '7♥', '7♦', '8♠', '8♣', '8♥', '8♦', '9♠', '9♣', '9♥', '9♦', 'T♠', 'T♣', 'T♥', 'T♦', 'J♠', 'J♣', 'J♥', 'J♦', 'Q♠', 'Q♣', 'Q♥', 'Q♦', 'K♠', 'K♣', 'K♥', 'K♦']
>>> len(deck)
52
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(deck)
>>> p1 = [deck.pop() for _ in range(5)]  # deal 5 cards...
>>> p2 = [deck.pop() for _ in range(5)]
>>> p1
['8♣', '9♠', '7♦', 'T♣', '9♦']
>>> p2
['6♣', '2♠', '6♠', '3♥', '5♦']
>>> len(deck)
42
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that both "player 1" and "player 2" receive unique cards from the same list, you can use the random.sample function in combination with list comprehension to remove the cards already dealt to "player 1" from the list before dealing to "player 2." Here's how you can do it:

```
import random
cards = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

# Deal cards to player 1
player_1 = random.sample(cards, 2)

# Remove the cards dealt to player 1 from the list
cards = [card for card in cards if card not in player_1]

# Deal cards to player 2 from the remaining cards
player_2 = random.sample(cards, 2)

print("Player 1:", player_1)
print("Player 2:", player_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new list with total cards drawn and then distribute it amongst players

```
import random
cards=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

#Draws 4 cards
cards_drawn = random.sample(cards,4)
print(cards_drawn)

#Distributes cards amongst players 
player_1 = cards_drawn[0:2]
player_2 = cards_drawn[2:4]

print(player_1)
print(player_2)
```